# Move a file from a git repository to a working folder?

Tags: git, github

I've created a local git repo, and uploaded to GitHub. It is housed in a local folder named `~/GitHub/WhatAreTheOdds`. The repo/folder contains one executable file named `oddsr.sh` (a shell script), and an assortment of  "support files" (README, wiki, license, etc, etc).

I want to keep `oddsr.sh` in a location outside the git repo folder - in a folder called `~/scripts`.  I have other scripts in `~/scripts`, and subfolders containing output data. It is just more convenient for me to work with `oddsr.sh` from the `~/scripts` folder.

I will occasionally make edits to `~/scripts/oddsr.sh`. When I make these changes, I would like for them to be picked up by git so that I am prompted to synchronize my local repo with GitHub. I use the `GitHub Desktop` app for this.

Is it possible for git (or more specifically the GitHub Desktop app) to include the file `~/scripts/oddsr.sh` in the repo? I do not want to maintain an additional copy in `~/GitHub/WhatAreTheOdds/oddsr.sh`

It seems to me this would be common practice, but perhaps not. I've searched, but I may be using the wrong terms to describe what I want to do. I have read a piece about `git mv`, but after some reading, it's not clear this will do what I want.

Can I keep a file outside the git repo, yet have git maintain version control over it?

Answer (score 0):

Use can just go to your shell (terminal, Git Bash, etc.), then navigate to your repository.
Then type

```
git mv ~/GitHub//WhatAreTheOdds/oddsr.sh ~/scripts/oddsr.sh
```

This will move your file to the scripts folder.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is NO.

`git` only tracks everything inside the root folder where repo is initialized.

eg:

```
> cd my_repo
> git init
```

After the above command, `git` will track all files inside `my_repo` folder only. If you want to track anything outside this repo, you won't be able to do this, as `git` doesn't have any knowledge of files outside it's root folder(in this case `my_repo`).